# Find relationships between events

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a set of Events $(E_i)_i$ which have a probability $(P_i)_i$.
I am able to write each event as a sum of distinct events that form a partition of the space.

My goal is to find all the relationships between the probability of the events. So I am trying to find all relationships like:

- $\sum \lambda _i P_i = T$
- $P_i \le P_j$ and more generically $\sum \lambda_i P_i * \sum \lambda_j P_j \le T$
- $P_i P_j = P_l$ and more generically $\sum \lambda_i P_i * \sum \lambda_j P_j = T$
- and other relationships (maybe using division, etc)

I have been able to solve the first type of relationships. Here's my process. I write the matrix of my events. Each column is an event, each row represents the realisation of the distinct event of my partition. So I get a boolean matrix that would look like this if I had 3 events, and a partition of 4 elements.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
Then calculating the kernel of that matrix gives me the relationship between the $(A_i)_i$, which are random variable that have a value of 1 if $A_i$ is true, 0 otherwise. The kernel gives me the linear combinations that sum to 0 of the $A_i$. By taking the expected value of that linear combination, I get the linear combinations between the probabilities. To solve it with $T \neq 0$, it is simply solving a linear equation

For the second category of relationships (inequalities, that is inclusion of events), does anyone know a good way to solve this (If you could also point me to an implementation, maybe in R or python, then that'd be great!). It seems to be in the category of "Linear matrix Inequality", on which I have no experience.

For the other category ($And$ relationships), any thoughts on how to solve this?

Generically, I feel I might be missing something. Is there a field of mathematics that addresses this question. Am I taking the wrong approach? Any suggestion very welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Event $E_i$ is a super-event of $E_j$ iff $A_i - A_j \ge 0$ where $A_k$ is the $k$-th column of your matrix. Thus finding all of these is multiplication $A\cdot M$ where $M = \begin{pmatrix}1 &1& -1& -1& 0& 0\\ -1& 0& 1& 0& 1& -1 \\ 0& -1& 0& 1& -1& 1\end{pmatrix}$ And then taking the column-wise minimum of the result. The vector contains $-1$ where $E_i \not\subset E_j$ and $0$ or $1$ otherwise. It will look like
$\text{colmin}(AM) = ()$

Comment: ... $= (E_1 \supset E_2, E_1 \supset E_3, E_2 \supset E_1, E_3 \supset E_1, E_2 \supset E_3, E_3 \supset E_2)$. For a larger number of events, $M$ will be a $|E| \times |E|(|E|-1)$-Matrix

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help.